# no result with scale_fill_manual and stat_summary for two bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am puzzled on how to set different colours for two bars
The grouping factor is "type"
The score variable is "score"

I use stat_summary to get for each type a bar with the mean score.
How to give the bars different colours using scale_fill_manual?

```
type=factor(c("A","A","A","B","B"))
score=c(1,2,3,11,12)
df = data.frame(type,score)

bar2= ggplot(df, aes(type,score))

bar2 + stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="bar", fill="White", colour="Black") +
scale_fill_manual("type", values = c("A" = "#3366FF", "B" = "#336633")) +
labs(x = "Type of Activity", y="Average Results")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `scale_fill_*` refers to the `fill` aes, otherwise is ignored.

Use `fill` inside `aes` and drop the static `fill="white"`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(type, score, fill=type)) + 
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="bar", colour="Black") +
  scale_fill_manual("type", values = c("A" = "#3366FF", "B" = "#336633")) +
  labs(x = "Type of Activity", y="Average Results")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>